# How to find out if a friend of mine is friend with a mutual friend of mine

Tags: facebook, friends

The name of the friend of mine is A and I can see only the mutual friends that we have, not all his friends. The name of the person that I'm not friend with on Facebook but has 3 other mutual friends is B. I can't see his friends either, except his 3 friends we have in common. How to find out if A and B are friends?

Comment: "except his 3 friends we have in common". That list would include A if A and B were friends, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can see the relationship between two users by using their username or Facebook id.

Use the below link if you know the username:

https://www.facebook.com/USER1?and=USER2

Where USER1 is A and USER2 is B.

If you have Facebook id instead of username, use this link:

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=ID1&and=ID2

Where ID1 is A's Facebook id and ID2 is B's Facebook id.

<sup>This is the developer way.</sup>

Comment: This doesn't give me a list, just the number and two example friends they have in common.  But I have found a solution and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Message function, and ask A if they are connected to B.

Comment: I would like to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://searchisback.com/.

It will generate a search query that looks like this:
https://www.facebook.com/search/ID1/friends/ID2/friends/intersect/
where ID1 and ID2 are the Facebook IDs of the queried users.

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished creating a free online tool that can quickly determine and display the mutual friends between not just two but multiple facebook users.
You can visit it on https://seemutualfriendsonfacebook.com. It does require a bit of work beforehand. The tool needs to get the friend lists of the facebook users as csv files. However there exists a chrome browser extension that allows you to easily scrape publicly visible friend lists and download them as `csv` files. Its called the Instant data scraper from the company webrobots.

After you've downloaded the friend lists of all the facebook users you want to compare you simply upload each file into the app and press **display mutual friends**. The mutual friends will then be displayed in a table and can be downloaded as a csv file as well.