# How to see a list of mutual friends of two Facebook accounts?

Tags: facebook

I can see the Friend Lists of two other users who aren't friends: call them A and B. How can you see all mutual friends between A and B, instead of cross-referencing yourself inefficiently?

[This solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92805/72255) fails.
I don't understand [this other recommendation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/103534/72255) quoted beneath: what ought be on https://searchisback.com/? It doesn't let me input A or B's names.

> Use https://searchisback.com/.
>
> It will generate a search query that looks like this:
> https://www.facebook.com/search/ID1/friends/ID2/friends/intersect/
> where ID1 and ID2 are the Facebook IDs of the queried users.

Comment: The first link is working for me. What didn't work for you and what error you are getting. please explain.

Comment: @serenesat The 1st link works too, but I do not understand what steps to take there. What exactly do you input? I see no option for mutual friends between 2 other people?

Comment: Just enter the username of first and second person, it will show the interaction between them. If you don't know the username, you can use their Facebook id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out if a friend of mine is friend with a mutual friend of mine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/how-to-find-out-if-a-friend-of-mine-is-friend-with-a-mutual-friend-of-mine)

Comment: have you found out a workable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple technique:

1. Find Profile ID of `B` - say it is Profile_B
2. Go to FB profile of `A` - say URL for which is `facebook.com/profile_A`
3. Append URL with following text `?and=Profile_B`. The final URL looks like `facebook.com/profile_A?and=Profile_B`

It would be finally redirected as `https://www.facebook.com/friendship/Profile_A/Profile_B`

You should be good with enough information.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: @triForce420 Not for me either. Isn't this the same as https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92805/72255, which fails, as I wrote in my post?

Comment: everyone, if this answer doesn't work for you, [please downvote it](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/63572)

Answer (score 0):

## Promising but currently not working solution

[Social Graph](http://vikhyat.net/projects/social_graph/) can be a way to do this. However, at the moment of writing (2019), Facebook refuses to allow logging in because it is outdated. I have emailed the author about this.

Other defunct services: [Nexus friend grapher](http://nexus.ludios.net/), [TouchGraph](http://www.touchgraph.com/company/services)

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished creating a free online tool that can quickly determine and display the mutual friends between not just two but multiple facebook users.
You can visit it on https://seemutualfriendsonfacebook.com. It does require a bit of work beforehand. The tool needs to get the friend lists of the facebook users as csv files. However there exists a chrome browser extension that allows you to easily scrape publicly visible friend lists and download them as `csv` files. Its called the Instant data scraper from the company webrobots.

After you've downloaded the friend lists of all the facebook users you want to compare you simply upload each file into the app and press **display mutual friends**. The mutual friends will then be displayed in a table and can be downloaded as a csv file as well.